# git tree hash does not show blobs

Tags: git, gitlab

I performed a git commit and was successfully able to push a file to remote repo.
Upon checking the git tree of the commit, did not find the blob hash that was committed to git.

```
Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ vi second-file.txt

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        second-file.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/main/resources/second-file.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git commit
[master 3fb459d] Git Commit#2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 src/main/resources/second-file.txt

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 497 bytes | 497.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://gitlab.com/shalabh_chaturvedi/gittest.git
   8d6d403..3fb459d  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git log
commit 3fb459d6a2104d8335e27b45b8f79f20aca78428 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: Shalabh Chaturvedi <shalabhchaturvedi@icloud.com>
Date:   Tue Aug 4 01:11:59 2020 +0530

    Git Commit#2

    Add second file with some git commands

commit 8d6d403def38cf8b611b14823d15455b4dc20c5a
Author: shalabh chaturvedi <shalabhchaturvedi@icloud.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 1 22:14:40 2020 +0530

    Commit id #1

    Create a file Intro.txt with content 'Hello git'

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git cat-file -p 3fb459d6a2104d8335e27b45b8f79f20aca78428
tree 93fc6f1481138e1d2de420f2d834a1c8b02a9259
parent 8d6d403def38cf8b611b14823d15455b4dc20c5a
author Shalabh Chaturvedi <shalabhchaturvedi@icloud.com> 1596483719 +0530
committer Shalabh Chaturvedi <shalabhchaturvedi@icloud.com> 1596483719 +0530

Git Commit#2

Add second file with some git commands

Shalabh@LAPTOP-O9UDCPOI MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/gittest/src/main/resources (master)
$ git cat-file -p 93fc6f1481138e1d2de420f2d834a1c8b02a9259
100644 blob 70ebc1f9607fab6ed8fc5fa58f0f582716f07f50    pom.xml
040000 tree 01267bfb4ca46c032b5ed7954be3e3c72630d0fe    src
```

In gitlab account I can see 'second-file.txt' attached to the commit. Did I use any wrong commands or is there any other way to get the file attached to the tree hash.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave to dig inside src:

```
git cat-file -p 01267bfb4ca46c032b5ed7954be3e3c72630d0fe
```

Use the id that will be shown for main:

```
git cat-file -p the-id-for-main
```

Use the id for resources:

```
git cat-file -p the-id-for-resources
```

Then you will see the id for the blob for second-file.txt... or in a single shot:

```
git cat-file -p 3fb459d6a2104d8335e27b45b8f79f20aca78428:src/main/resources
```

Comment: Thanks eftshift0. I finally found my respective blob. Could you please also confirm why git created this hierarchical tree structure and blob was not attached directly to tree hash  93fc6f1481138e1d2de420f2d834a1c8b02a9259?

Comment: You could have seen the id of the blob with `git ls-tree -r 3fb459d6a2104d8335e27b45b8f`

Comment: ... or with `git ls-tree 3fb459d6a2104d8335e27b45b8f -- src/main/resources/second-file.txt`

Comment: Could you please also confirm why git created this hierarchical tree structure and blob was not attached directly to tree hash 93fc6f1481138e1d2de420f2d834a1c8b02a9259?

Comment: Remember that Linus (_the_ Linus) is a very OS-centric developer.... so he followed on the analogy of directories and files.... just like in a OS. And it allows for _a lot_ of flexibility so I don't see the need to have a _single_ tree with lots of blobs with paths that have `/`s inside.

Comment: Note that Git will compress, or even re-use, these tree objects. If you have a project that has a top level tree with `a/` `b/` and `c/` subdirectories and you modify something in `c/`  but not in `a/` and not in `b/`, you wind up re-using the existing `b/` tree object (but not the existing `a/` or `c/` since both of those have new hash IDs). The new `c/` and `a/` likely compress well against the previous `c/` and `a/` trees when Git later goes to pack these objects, too.

Comment: One could argue that a new single (flattened) tree would still compress well against its predecessor. I think this is true. Statistically, the single flattened tree object would work just as well as the single flattened index. We've seen in very large repositories, though, that the single flattened index *doesn't* work that well sometimes. What's not completely clear is why Git uses a flattened index and a tree-structured set of trees. :-)